# Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined, while running hyperledger fabric project

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

response while invoking and querying

```
Cannot read property 'curve' of undefined
    at Object.KEYUTIL.getKey (/home/quolam-002/Documents/Hyperledger_Fabric proejct/fabric-samples/vytalconnect2/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/jsrsasign/lib/jsrsasign.js:247:10379)
    at CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.getKey (/home/quolam-002/Documents/Hyperledger_Fabric proejct/fabric-samples/vytalconnect2/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/impl/CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES.js:206:27)
```

Comment: I get this error whenever I stop the container and start it again. If the containers are running continuously, this error is not seen however. Expiry date for certificates generated by crypto-config are large values, so it is not the case that they have expired. What could be the case?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem of certificates,

if you are following balance transfer example of fabric samples (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer) then

1. first delete the fabric-client-kv-* folder
2. again run the runApp.sh and testAPIs.sh scripts

else

1. look for the folder where enrolled user certificates are placed
2. delete that folder
3. Tear down the network (stop and remove all the running containers  )
4. Again Register and enroll users in the network.

cause of the problem :-

the value of curve key inside client object is undefined

```
  _cryptoSuite: 
   CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES {
     _keySize: 256,
     _hashAlgo: 'SHA2',
     _cryptoKeyStore: 
      CryptoKeyStore {
        logger: [Object],
        _store: null,
        _storeConfig: [Object],
        _getKeyStore: [Function] },
     _curveName: 'secp256r1',
     _ecdsaCurve: 
      PresetCurve {
        curve: undefined,
        g: <EC Point x: 6b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296 y: 4fe342e2fe1a7f9b8ee7eb4a7c0f9e162bce33576b315ececbb6406837bf51f5>,
        n: <BN: ffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffbce6faada7179e84f3b9cac2fc632551>,
        hash: [Object] },
     _hashFunction: [Function],
     _hashOutputSize: 32,
     _ecdsa:   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to an invalid certificate you're using, you can check the validity of your certificate suing

1. [ssldecoder](https://ssldecoder.org/)
2. [sslshopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html)

For more info follow this medium article [Link](https://medium.com/@thotanarendranathreddy/hyperledger-fabric-multi-org-multi-channel-kafka-consensus-multi-orderers-errors-9c393791663a)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to invalid/expired certificates.

You could delete the certs which are already present.teardown the network and start the network again by using the scripts presents.for eg startfabric.sh for fabcar.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. look for the folder where enrolled user certificates are placed
2. delete that folder
3. Tear down the network (stop and remove all the running containers )
4. Again Register and enroll users in the network.
```

This above troubleshooting step solves error in my error too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is because your ECDSA keys are probably deleted after certain time once the network is restarted. When you register/enroll via the API as in the `balance-transfer` example, the crypto store path configured in `/artifacts/client-org1.yaml` is set as `/tmp/fabric-client-kv-org1`. You may try updating the path to something outside of `/tmp` so it persists across restarts. This worked for me.

A simple deletion of `fabric-client-kv-*` directory may work in the short run but may not be suitable in the long run especially in the production environment.